# Technical term for a while loop where conditional goes in middle of the block?

Tags: while-loop, do-while

I know there are normal while loops:

```
while(conditional_statement) {
    // some code
}
```

do while loops:

```
do {
    // some code
} while(conditional_statement);
```

and a third kind of while loop:

```
do {
    // some code
} while(conditional_statement) {
    // some more code
}
```

but I can't recall the name of the third kind. I know that most languages only implement the first two types of while loops. If you can remember the name of the third type of while loop, it would be a real bonus if you could mention the languages which allow this type of while loop.

EDIT:
I know that the functionality of the third kind of while loop can be implemented by doing the following:

```
while(true) {
    // some code
    if(!conditional_statement) break;
    // some more code
}
```

I'm purely interested in the **technical name** of the third kind of while loop.

Comment: I haven't encountered the third construct. How is this supposed to work? When is the body after the while statement executed?

Comment: The first body is executed, then the conditional is checked. If the conditional evaluates to true, then the second body is executed. Then the process repeats.

Comment: I see. I would also be interested in which languages this is implemented.

Comment: The third method is not a standardized one afaik. I do not know of any language that supports that construct.
I quickly looked around on google, but found nothing like you describe.... so maybe there is no official technical name....